# How to Draw a Bitmap image in a arc shape in android to create a spin

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint

I am trying to create a spin in android. Well i have used a library code to create spin like below image:

[Spin Example in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fckjz.jpg)

The help i want is to fit the spin images to the arc.

The method canvas.drawArc() only accept the paint also i tried with canvas.drawBitmap() but that does not fix in the arc shape.

Here is the Sample code for creating a slice of the spin with background color:

```
Paint mArcPaint = new Paint();
private RectF mRange = new RectF();

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

   for (int i = 0; i < 6 i++) {

       mArcPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       mArcPaint.setColor(mLuckyItemList.get(i).color);   //Color of a Pie
       canvas.drawArc(mRange, tmpAngle, sweepAngle, true, mArcPaint); //Different Float value instead of angles

     }
}
```

I hope somebody from community solves my problem.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/adef145/SpinningWheelAndroid) Libarry https://github.com/adef145/SpinningWheelAndroid  SpinningWheelAndroid

Comment: Bro i am using that library only!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a [BitmapShader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader), select it to the paint object then draw an arc.